# Why do the return results of IIF and ISNULL not match my expectation when using date values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use IIF() to return the cast of a column as a date but only when the value isn't a blank string [the values are not being stored as a null in the database I am working with].

I tried to use ISNULL as a better intermediary but because a date returns as 1900-01-01 it isn't working correctly. It seems to work with other data types (int).

Example table

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_test (
[reg_dt] varchar(10)
)
insert into #temp_test SELECT ''
insert into #temp_test SELECT ''
insert into #temp_test SELECT ''
insert into #temp_test SELECT ''
INSERT INTO #temp_test select '20080509'
select * from #temp_test
```

Example of IIF test (appears to function properly, I have also tested the inverse ='', 'false', 'true'); when I uncomment the try_convert and remove 'true', an error is encountered

```
SELECT IIF([reg_dt] != '', 'true'
       --TRY_CONVERT(date, [reg_dt], 112)
       , 'false') [reg_dt]
FROM   [#temp_test];
```

Example of ISNULL (returns 1900-01-01)

```
SELECT ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT( DATE, [reg_dt], 112), '') [reg_dt] from [#temp_test]
```

I expect the output to be a blank value if the existing value was blank and, if not, a date value to be returned. 
I think converting to date before checking for null values would probably be best, because if an invalid date is passed (such as 04/31/2019) then that would be converted to a blank value which is the preferred functionality in this case.

The below code DOES work but I'm really not sure if this is the best way to do it.

```
select ISNULL(NULLIF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST([reg_dt] as date), 112), '19000101'), '') as [reg_dt] from #temp_test
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a blank string that is a date. When you pass an empty string to a date time it will perform an implicit conversion and you get 1900-01-01. If you really want empty strings you will have to use character data, not dates. And really you should use the proper datatypes for dates instead of varchar.

Comment: Hi Sean - the data that's being passed is all varchar and I am trying to successfully convert it, which is how I'm encountering this problem. I commented below (and should edit my main to include) that  select ISNULL(NULLIF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST([reg_dt] as date), 112), '19000101'), '') as [reg_dt] from #temp_test works but I don't understand if that's really the best way to do this. Because the behavior is changing '' to 1900-01-01 as you confirmed, I guess that's what I have to detect in this case? If I was designing this from scratch I would never have accepted all varchar data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect the output to be a blank value if the existing value was
>   blank and, if not, a date value to be returned.

Every column from the result set must have a data type. `DATE` and `DATETIME` data types can't hold empty stings, only valid dates or `NULL`. If you want to see an empty string, then you will have to work with a string data type, like `VARCHAR`.

Check these examples:

```
DECLARE @Varchar VARCHAR(100) = ''

SELECT
    EmptyVarchar = @Varchar,
    EmptyVarcharAsDate = CONVERT(DATE, @Varchar),
    CaseExpression = CASE WHEN @Varchar = '' THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(DATE, @Varchar) END
```

Result:

```
EmptyVarchar    EmptyVarcharAsDate  CaseExpression
                1900-01-01          1900-01-01
```

If we check which data type the `CASE` is actually returning...

```
DECLARE @Varchar VARCHAR(100) = ''

SELECT
    ResultType = SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(
        CASE WHEN @Varchar = '' THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(DATE, @Varchar) END, 
        'BaseType')
```

Result:

```
ResultType
date
```

You see that the `CASE` (an `IIF` works similar) is returning a date type, so the empty string is implicitly converting to the default date of `1900-01-01`.

A way to handle dates and return them as an empty strings when they can't be converted would be the following:

```
DECLARE @VarcharDates TABLE (VarcharDate VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @VarcharDates (VarcharDate)
VALUES
    (''),
    (NULL),
    ('NULL'),
    ('15'),
    ('2019'),
    ('2019-05'),
    ('31/01/2000'),
    ('1800-01-01'),
    ('20190503'),
    ('20190503111111')

SELECT
    V.VarcharDate,
    DateAsVarchar = CASE 
        WHEN V.VarcharDate = '' THEN ''
        ELSE ISNULL(
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), TRY_CONVERT(DATE, V.VarcharDate, 112)),
            '') END
FROM
    @VarcharDates AS V
```

Result:

```
VarcharDate     DateAsVarchar

NULL    
NULL    
15  
2019            2019-01-01
2019-05 
31/01/2000  
1800-01-01  
20190503        2019-05-03
20190503111111
```

Comment: Hi Ezlo, I appreciate your reply. This makes sense but it leaves me confused - IIF is converted to a case statement by the SQL engine, is my understanding, so why does your code work but not mine? When I run a select in SQL with the below, it seems to work, but then the data isn't being interpreted as a date on the end result. ```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE ( [reg_dt] varchar(12) )
insert into @TestTable (reg_dt) values (''), (' '), ('20001111'), (NULL)

select ISNULL(NULLIF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST([reg_dt] as date), 112), '19000101'), '') as [reg_dt] from @TestTable ```

Comment: Figured out what's causing the errors, I think - example: `DECLARE @TestTable TABLE ( [reg_dt] varchar(12) )
insert into @TestTable (reg_dt) values (''), (' '), ('20001111'), (NULL), ('20190431')

select ISNULL(NULLIF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST([reg_dt] as date), 112), '19000101'), '') as [reg_dt] from @TestTable;` this causes a fail to convert because of the invalid date format. So it must need a try-convert statement as well, which I tried in a previous iteration and you recommended. I think this should be enough to get me to the end.

Answer (score 2):

NULL is not equal to an empty string. An empty string is converted to '1900-01-01' which is a valid date. If you want to have NULLs, you need to specify NULL.

By the way, a comparison with NULL won't return true nor false. It will return unknown.

Here's an example based on yours.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_test (
[reg_dt] varchar(10)
)
insert into #temp_test SELECT ''
insert into #temp_test SELECT NULL
INSERT INTO #temp_test select '20080509'

SELECT IIF([reg_dt] != '', 'true', 'false') [reg_dt]
FROM   [#temp_test];

SELECT [reg_dt],
    TRY_CONVERT( DATE, [reg_dt], 112) [converted_reg_dt],
    ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT( DATE, [reg_dt], 112), '') [formatted_reg_dt] 
from [#temp_test];
```

Comment: Hi Luis, I know that NULL != '' but that's exactly the problem I expressed. On the table I'm taking these values from the blank strings are what is embedded - there are no null values. The only way I've been able to make this work so far is to use like 
```
 select ISNULL(NULLIF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST([reg_dt] as date), 112), '19000101'), '') as [reg_dt] from #temp_test
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL cannot return multiple datatypes in for single columns so it has to convert all value to DATE. If I understand correctly, it seems like you want to check if the date is valid and then return varchar (blanks)
How about this then:

```
SELECT CASE reg_dt WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE CAST(TRY_CONVERT(date, [reg_dt], 112) AS varchar(20)) END AS YourDate FROM [#temp_test]
```

Comment: This makes sense but if that's the case then why is my snippet working - is it returning a varchar instead? I even simplified it to this:    ISNULL(NULLIF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CB38E588-DBA4-428F-B1B5-D30E2C661187], 112), '19000101'), '') as [purchase_dt] as an example of a successful line.

Comment: I think it does; BOL: NULLIF Returns the same type as the first expression.

Comment: ISNULL(NULLIF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), cast([6BCFDECC-01C6-4647-88DF-F13766F0B8F4] as date), 112), '19000101'), '') as [first_seen_vin]

Gonna give this a shot.